# How to ptotect non-browser based webservice with saml

Tags: web-services, wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

I want to protect non-browser based web service with saml using wso2is. please provide me some links or tutorial to do this. So far I google about this but I didn't get idea how to do this. please help. thnx

Answer (score 1):

To protect non-Browser based web services with SAML we need the ECP Profiles. But in the current implementation of the WSO2 Identity server, it doesn't support ECP profiles. It will be implemented in future releases.